# How to edit /system/bin/lpr in Samsung S4 i9295 running 5.0.1 Lollipop

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, samsung, samsung-galaxy-s-4, system

How do I edit /system/bin files in Android since after 4.x? Has something changed? I seem to recall just opening the file playlpm on the device in a text editor and seeing and making needed modifications thusly:

```
#!/system/bin/sh
 /system/bin/reboot
```

Now I am seeing black diamonds with question marks and unintelligible character strings. What's changed here? Are these shell scripts compiled?!? Have I spaced out an important step? TIA for clarification. 
PS...device is rooted, browser is Root Browser v2.2.3, and test editors I've tried are RB Text Editor, and DroidEdit.

Comment: If an editor displays weird characters, that means your file is compiled (e.g., a binary, not a shell script).

Comment: Yeah, roger that, but they were editable in a text editor prior to 5.x , correct? There are lots of posts about editing /system/bin files by what appears to be simply opening them and changing code with a text editor...I'd just like to confirm that something has changed w/out having to load a 4.x ROM. Thanks.

Comment: As said above, **/system/bin** can contain two **different** types of files: *shell scripts* (editable via a trivial text editor) and *binary executables* (compiled, can be edited via an hex editor).